# How to get 'outer shell' of self-intersecting polygon

Tags: javascript, polygon, computational-geometry, turfjs

I have a self-intersecting / winding polygon (see in green on picture below). I'd like to get the outer shell (by only keeping the edges that are on the outside of the polygon / removing any inside edges) and therefore end up with a well-defined polygon without any holes inside (see solution in yellow on picture).

[image]

How could I do this? Convex/concave hulls won't do because they will take some ground outside the polygon.

I'm using turf-js, so any solution using that would be ideal, but happy to use other libraries / write an algorithm for scratch if not possible.

Comment: Thanks @Yves, will check those out! A solution I've thought about since is adding a small buffer to the line (this removes any kinks), and then removing any holes left inside the polygon. If the buffer is small enough, it should be indistinguishible from the original shape

Comment: It does ease the problem massively - by buffering the line above, the three kinks that form that middle hole disappear. This leaves you with a Polygon that has a well-defined outer ring, and inner ring for that hole. You can simply 'delete' the inner-ring  and you're left with a polygon without holes. The only downside is that the shape expands a bit, but you can take a negative buffer afterwards to offset this

Comment: I won't contradict you more. Good luck.